# Download 100MB PDF and save it in SD Card

Tags: android, pdf, download

I have tried many samples to download the Pdf file and saving in the SD and it worked fine for 5MB files ,How can I download a 50 mb or more size's pdf file ? I am getting `OutOfMemoryException`. In iPhone upto 100MB sized pdf is also gets downloaded. Is there any source code to download 50Mb PDF in Android ?

Comment: Do you have enough memory on the phone to download the file? check that first.

Comment: I'm Using 16GB sd I have 2GB memory free. but still i'm not able to process

Comment: What android phone are you using that is currently available and has 2GB RAM?

Comment: is the 2gb free on the SD card or on the phone memory?

Comment: @user1242748  Have you try this Tutorial No 9 in this http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: I 'm Using ASUS Tablet Transformer TF101, I have Free memory in SD .

Answer (score 0):

i use FTP (Chilkat Library - http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatAndroid.asp) .. worked for me perfectly.